# How to bring back removed spaces from a string

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, caesar-cipher

I have windows form application that encrypt the string and decrypt
it back using Caesar Algorithm. When encrypting a string I have to remove spaces from it ,but when I'll decrypt it again I should bring back the removed spaces into their actual places.

The problem I faced in this case is in bringing the removed spaces from the encrypted string and also when decrypting there are some letters are changed into special characters like this pattern where the encryption key is 3:

Plain text: My name is Shafaq Zahir
Encrypted text: PbqdphlvVkdidtCdklu
Decrypted text: M_nameisShafaq@ahir

This is my code

```
class CaesarAlgorithm
    {
        public string Encrypt(string pt,int key)
        {
            char[] buffer = pt.Replace(" ",string.Empty).ToCharArray();
            //char[] buffer = pt.ToCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<buffer.Length;i++)
            {
                if (buffer[i] >= 'a' && buffer[i] <= 'z')
                {
                    buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] + key);
                    if (buffer[i] > 'z')
                    {
                        buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] - 26);
                    }
                }
                else if (buffer[i] >= 'A' && buffer[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                    buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] + key);
                    if (buffer[i] > 'Z')
                    {
                        buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] - 26);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new string (buffer);

        }

        public string Decrypt(string pt,int key)
        {
            char[] buffer = pt.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                if (buffer[i] >= 'a' && buffer[i] <= 'z')
                {
                    buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] - key);
                    if (buffer[i] > 'z')
                    {
                        buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] - 26);
                    }
                }
                else if (buffer[i] >= 'A' && buffer[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                    buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] - key);
                    if (buffer[i] > 'Z')
                    {
                        buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] - 26);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new string(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your functions should better be called "ObfuscateAndDestruct" and "PartiallyReconstructWithFaults", because that is what they do. Never try to invent 'encryption' yourself, always find a library that does it well without making beginner mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this code

```
if (buffer[i] > 'Z')
 { 
buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] - 26);
 }
```

Be

```
if (buffer[i] <'A')
 { 
buffer[i] = (char)(buffer[i] + 26);
 }
```

In your **decrypt** function?
To check if it's less than A or a because you are subtracting key from it. 
Also don't replace spaces in your code. Just encrypt them and decrypt them they will stay, that said, there is no way to recover spaces unless you keep index information with it.!

Comment: yes sir that was a mistake made by me and you made me notis it ,so thanks for it and if you can suggest me a solution for bringing back the removed spaces I would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of right would be to loop through the original char array and save the index of each space then add it back the end, kinda just woke up so there's probably a better solution. Also just wondering why you can't have spaces

Comment: this was recommended in the assignment given by the professor

Comment: The problem is the OP's own "Encrypt" and "Decrypt" functions. Saving the indexes of arbitrary characters won't help at all. Where are those indexes going to be stored?

Comment: Id change the space to a specific character of less used options and then its easy to put it back

Comment: @MohammedShfq SO isn't a homework writing service. And Caesar's algorithm is a simple transposition algorithm. Your code does a *lot* more than transposing a character

Comment: Leave the spaces unchanged in your cyphertext and ignore them again when you decrypt.  How do you deal with other non-letters, like punctuation?

Comment: @rossum like it's shown in my code I check if the character array element is a letter then I push it into another array and encrypt it by adding the value of the ASSCI code of the character with the value of the key

Comment: You need to push spaces/punctuation as well and pass them through unchanged in both directions.